# Matlab Contradictory Rank for Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a diagonal matrix with values -3.4562e-14, 15.2673,  86.9550, 1.4873e+03. Matlab says that its rank is 3 and rref indicates the same. Why is this, and how can I figure out what's really going on? Further, this diagonal is from eigenvalue decomposition which returned four eigenvectors. The original matrix is:

```
[ 67.0000  103.0000  -44.5000 -133.5000; 
  103.0000  573.0000  -26.5000 -709.5000; 
 -44.5000  -26.5000   46.7500   20.2500; 
 -133.5000 -709.5000   20.2500  902.7500]
```

Comment: Rank computation also depends on the tolerance used. For example, try rank(v,eps). Basically, Matlab cannot tell whether -3.4562e-14 is the result of a numerical (round-off) error or an actual, really small value in the matrix.

Comment: Matlab is computing the rank, up to some precision. It does not do exact rank computation. Here -3.4e-14 is too small and is considered as a zero. See @g24l.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for such questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original matrix is ill conditioned. The smallest eigenvalue is of order 1e-14, which is near eps, and the largest is of order 1e+03.

The conditioning number is `larget singular value/smallest singular value` . In the case that the matrix is normal , which is your case also, that is `larget eigenvalue/smallest eigenvalue` .

This in you case is of order 1e+17, which is very large, and that is why the smallest eigenvalue is considered to be 0 by `rank`, that's why `rank` reports 3.

Comment: Well, actually MATLAB uses singular values, NOT eigenvalues. They need not always be the same.

Comment: @woodchips, thanks for the comment, that is indeed so. Personally, I did not imply that MATLAB uses eig for the conditioning number.

Comment: @g24l I read this again and realized it didn't make sense. I mean, I get the gist of it (precision error, derr), but the last eigenvalue _is_ the largest so your last sentence is false (if you meant "...the largest [eigenvalue]..."). Further, aren't there problems when something is _smaller_ than eps?

Comment: Did you mean smallest and 1e16?

Comment: @Jeff basically I'll rephrase with the conditioning number. see the new edit